# Shared Google Documents notifications

Tags: google-drive

I am an English teacher and have received shared documents from each of my students. I receive the initial email telling me I have a shared document, which is good.  I will make a comment about their writing and suggest corrections.  I do not want to receive any further emails **unless** a student replies to a comment. How does the student set up their account so that I get no further emails unless they reply to a comment?

Comment: I am curious: what kind of e-mails do you receive after the initial email telling you I have a shared document?

Comment: I may receive an email if they resolve a comment, or reply to a comment, I have even received an email as a student has edited their document.

Comment: Strange, I don't remember receiving email as a collaborator has edited their document, but anyway cool use case of Google doc!

Answer (score 1):

In the Google Drive document window, on the far right, there's a Comments box. Click on it and a dropdown will appear including an icon for Notifications. Click Notifications and there's an option for "Replies to you". Will that option do what you need?

Of course, next time Google redesign the UI this option may move somewhere completely different...

Comment: Is 'Replies to You' chosen by me (shared with) or by the owner of the document? Or by both?  Or does it matter?

Comment: Each user can add their own notification rule. It's like subscribing to receive emails - each visitor to a site can have a different subscription.